# Cannot understand CYK Algorithm pseudo-code

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, cyk

I was reading about the [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), and there is one part of pseudo-code I cannot understand. The whole pseudo-code is:

```
let the input be a string S consisting of n characters: a1 ... an.
let the grammar contain r nonterminal symbols R1 ... Rr.
This grammar contains the subset Rs which is the set of start symbols.
let P[n,n,r] be an array of booleans. Initialize all elements of P to false.
for each i = 1 to n
  for each unit production Rj -> ai
    set P[i,1,j] = true
for each i = 2 to n -- Length of span
  for each j = 1 to n-i+1 -- Start of span
    for each k = 1 to i-1 -- Partition of span
      for each production RA -> RB RC
        if P[j,k,B] and P[j+k,i-k,C] then set P[j,i,A] = true
if any of P[1,n,x] is true (x is iterated over the set s, where s are all the indices for Rs) then
  S is member of language
else
  S is not member of language
```

These parts are which I am confused:

```
    for each production RA -> RB RC
      if P[j,k,B] and P[j+k,i-k,C] then set P[j,i,A] = true
```

Would someone give some hints about these pseudocode?

Comment: @syb0rg: I intentionally leave the indentation, so that it is easier to locate the smaller snippet of code from the big chunk of code.

Comment: @nhahtdh Fixed (formatting habit, sorry).

Comment: @syb0rg: The indentation of the smaller code snippet is a bit off (you can just copy and paste from the original code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudocode

> For each production R<sub>A</sub> → R<sub>B</sub> R<sub>C</sub>:
>
> if P[j,k,B] and P[j+k,i-k,C] then set P[j,i,A] = true

Should be interpreted in the following way.  Suppose that it's the case that P[j, k, B] is true.  That means that the string formed from k characters starting at position j can derived from the nonterminal R<sub>B</sub>.  If it's also the case that P[j + k, i - k, C] is true, then the string formed from the i - k characters starting at position j + k can be derived from nonterminal R<sub>C</sub>.  Therefore, since R<sub>A</sub> → R<sub>B</sub> R<sub>C</sub> is a production, it's the case that the string formed from the i characters starting at position j can be derived from R<sub>A</sub>.

I think it might help to interpret that pseudocode as

> For each production R<sub>A</sub> → R<sub>B</sub> R<sub>C</sub>:
>
> if P[j,k,B] == true and P[j+k,i-k,C] == true, then set P[j,i,A] = true

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you clarify what the indexes A B and C are please？

Comment: @user2280838- The algorithm numbers all of the nonterminals R_1, R_2, ..., R_n.  Here, A, B, and C happen are the indices of the nonterminals in the production R_A -> R_B R_C.  For example, if the production was S -> T U and S had index 1, T had index 2, and U had index 3, then we would have A = 1, B = 2, and C = 3.  Does that help?

Comment: It does help but what if A B and C as non terminals are defined more than once in the grammar? Is the assignment of the index sort of an ID value that helps it being distinguished by other nonterminals?

Comment: @user2280838- The pseudocode works by assigning every nonterminal a unique ID.  You're not "redefining" the same nonterminal twice if you associate multiple productions with it; it's the same nonterminal each time.  This means that even if you have something like S -> UT and S -> XY, the S is the same in both cases (and has the same index).