# Something wrong with my CYK code

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, cyk

I wrote some code implementing the [CYK Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm). I have some problems with my code, but I don't know which I did wrong. I also [asked about the pseudo-code of CYK Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006194/cannot-understand-cyk-algorithm-pseudo-code).

Could you please help me with this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class cyk {

    public static int findIndex(ArrayList<String[]> Grammar, String symbol) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Grammar.size(); i++) {
            String[] rule = Grammar.get(i);
            if (rule.length == 2) {
                if (symbol.equals(Grammar.get(i)[0]))
                    return i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Grammar.size(); i++) {
            if (symbol.equals(Grammar.get(i)[0]))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static boolean cyk(String S, ArrayList<String[]> Grammar) {
        int n = S.length();
        int r = Grammar.size();

        boolean P[][][] = new boolean[n][n][r];
        initializeP(P, n, r);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
                String[] rule = (String[]) Grammar.get(j);
                if (rule.length == 2) {
                    if (rule[1].equals(String.valueOf(S.charAt(i)))) {
                        P[i][0][j] = true;

                        //System.out.println(S.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i + 1; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
                    // for each production RA -> RB RC
                    for (int m = 0; m < r; m++) {
                        String[] rule = Grammar.get(m);
                        if (rule.length > 2) {
                            int A = findIndex(Grammar, rule[0]);
                            int B = findIndex(Grammar, rule[1]);
                            int C = findIndex(Grammar, rule[2]);
                            if (P[i][k][B] && P[j + k][i - k][C])
                                P[j][i][A] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//       for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
//       System.out.print(P[1][i][k] + " ");
//       }
//       System.out.println();
//       }
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            if (P[0][n-1][i])
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void initializeP(boolean P[][][], int n, int r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
                    P[i][j][k] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * If size of production is >2 its not unit production
         */
        String input = "aabb";
        ArrayList<String[]> Grammar = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] rule = { "A", "a" };
        Grammar.add(rule);
        String[] rule1 = { "A", "A", "A" };
        Grammar.add(rule1);
        String[] rule2 = { "B", "B", "B" };
        Grammar.add(rule2);
        String[] rule5 = { "B", "b" };
        Grammar.add(rule5);
        String[] rule3 = { "S", "A", "B" };
        Grammar.add(rule3);
        System.out.println(cyk(input, Grammar));

    }
}
```

Thank you guys!

EDIT:

After debugging the code for a while I have found the part of the code that is not working.

It is ：

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n - i + 1; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) {
                        // for each production RA -> RB RC
                        for (int m = 0; m < r; m++) {
                            String[] rule = Grammar.get(m);
                            if (rule.length > 2) {
                                int A = findIndex(Grammar, rule[0]);
                                int B = findIndex(Grammar, rule[1]);
                                int C = findIndex(Grammar, rule[2]);
                                if (P[i][k][B] && P[j + k][i - k][C])
                                    P[j][i][A] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I suspect that the bug is related to the first question I had. It is most likely regarding the way I interpretation of the indexes of A B and C. Could someone take a look and see if findIndex is the right way to find indexes?

Comment: What specifically is your question?  We will not answer questions of the form "what's wrong with my code?" unless you've given us a description of what specific problems you're having, what you've tried so far to fix it, and where you think the problem is.

Comment: The problem is related to the output of the code. It is expected to be true but it is false. I only implemented the Wikipedia CYK algorithm page and I would expect it to work as intended.

Comment: You need to do your own debugging attempt first.  Trace through the code in a debugger, or put in `println`s to try to see what it's doing.  Again, please make a good, honest effort to figure this out before you ask here.

Comment: I apologize if I gave you that impression I tried debugging before posting here. I just did more research and estimated a better range of faulty code. Thanks for your help.